# SQL Like in OWL API for data properties

Tags: owl, owl-api

In OWL API, classes may have data properties. For e.g. a class may have a date property `hasCommonName "Something"`. In OWL API, is there any facility like the SQL like which allows querying for classes that hasCommonName containing the word "Some", just like SQL like behave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to identify the things you need. Consider the following knowledge base:

```
DataProperty: hasCommonName

Individual: foo

Facts:  
 hasCommonName "Something"
```

You can retrieve the individual `foo` by using the following class expression: `hasCommonName some string[pattern "Some.*"]`. The `string[pattern "Some.*"]` specifies the pattern to be matched. Warning, currently not supported by all reasoners (works for Hermit 1.3.7)

Comment: if this is supported by factpp, then great because factpp is very fast

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at some SPARQL tutorials. You can write something like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassof [
  owl:onProperty :hasTopping;
  owl:someValuesFrom :TomatoTopping ] .
}
```

Basically, you need to define the correct predicate based on your restriction.